# how to get last consequently rows with same value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can somebody help me with this task for MSSQL?
I have confusing for few days :o(
We have rows which show you chages the States of machine in the time.

```
     datetime          worker   order   state   break
-----------------------------------------------------
2014-01-20 13:00:00     1458    123456  1       2
2014-01-20 12:00:00     1458    123456  1       1
2014-01-20 11:22:22     1458    123456  1       NULL
2014-01-20 09:35:44     1458    123456  3       NULL
2014-01-20 09:00:22     1458    940266  1       NULL
2014-01-20 08:30:07     1458    940266  5       NULL
2014-01-20 08:15:04     1458    940266  1       NULL
2014-01-20 07:47:38     1458    940266  3       NULL
```

If last state is for example "1", then I would by get all rows (resp. first occurence) immediately precede this Last row with same state value "1".(consequently)
Other words, I would by get this row:

```
2014-01-20 11:22:22     1458    123456  1       NULL
```

From this time standing state "1".
P.S.: num ocurrences last row with concrete value can by more but can by only one too. In this case I woul by get simply last row.

Thank for reply.

Comment: I'm very sorry and don't mean to be rude but language barrier is preventing me (and I would guess others) from understanding what you're asking here.

Comment: in your example - the result shouldn't be 2014-01-20 12:00:00     1458    123456  1       1 ??

Comment: Not clear mate, what records do you want that precede 014-01-20 11:22:22?

Comment: @Mzf I also think that's what OP meant. The 2014-01-20 12:00:00 state 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to identify the sequence of "1"s and find the earliest date where it started.  The following query does this, with the explanation to follow:

```
select top 1 t.*
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by worker order by datetime desc) -
              row_number() over (partition by worker, state order by datetime desc)
             ) as diff
      from t
     ) t
where diff = 0
order by datetime asc
```

This is going to be a bit challenging to explain.  `row_number()` assigns a sequential number to groups of rows, the group defined by the `partition by`.  The ordering within the group is defined by the `order by`.

This orders things for the worker, with the most recent getting a value of 1.  It then orders things for each worker/state, with the most recent getting a value of 1.  The difference is 0 only when for the last state.  The final query selects the first row by time.

Here is what the row numbers and diffs look like for your data:

```
     datetime          worker   order   state   break   rn     rn   diff
-----------------------------------------------------  worker w/st
2014-01-20 13:00:00     1458    123456  1       2        1     1     0
2014-01-20 12:00:00     1458    123456  1       1        2     2     0
2014-01-20 11:22:22     1458    123456  1       NULL     3     3     0
2014-01-20 09:35:44     1458    123456  3       NULL     4     1     3
2014-01-20 09:00:22     1458    940266  1       NULL     5     4     1
2014-01-20 08:30:07     1458    940266  5       NULL     6     1     5
2014-01-20 08:15:04     1458    940266  1       NULL     7     5     2
2014-01-20 07:47:38     1458    940266  3       NULL     8     2     6
```

So the `where diff = 0` selects the first three rows.

Comment: "You want to identify the sequence of "1"s and find the earliest date where it started." If that's the case shouldn't you be partitioning by [order] in the query. Otherwise it doesn't match with OP's example somehow, does it?

Comment: @peter.petrov . . . I'm not sure what `order` has to do with it.  The OP is not clear, mentioning "machine" in the text, but having no such column in the data.  However, the OP does show only one result as the desired result, and that's why I used `worker`.

Comment: Yeah, OK, the question is quite unclear anyway. I was just guessing.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. Thank you very very much. Worked

Comment: @user3215680 . . . Glad I could help.  This is one of my favorite answers.

Comment: Sorry for my english :o)